# How do I give my non-Azure app access to Azure SQL Server without whitelisting an ip address?

Tags: azure-sql-database, role, active-directory

I have an app that is deployed to Vercel. It is registered in Azure AD and uses AAD for authentication. I added my personal ip to the whitelist, and when I run it locally, everything works as it should.

When I use the deployed version, auth works perfectly, but I'm unable to access Azure SQL Server. The ip addresses for the app servers are dynamic.

How can I give my app access to the database without whitelisting ip addresses? I've spent hours looking for a way to configure a service principal without any luck.

I see that Google Cloud has a thing called Cloud SQL Proxy, which sounds exactly like what I need. I'd rather not re-host my database though, so I hope Azure has the equivalent.

"GCP recommends the use of Cloud SQL Proxy instead of whitelisting IP address ranges to enable external applications to connect to the instance."

Answer (score 1):

You should use private endpoints to connect Azure SQL and your applications:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/private-endpoint-overview

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking/private-endpoint